# IComparer<> and class inheritance in C#

Tags: collections, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

Is there any way to implement specialized IComparer for the base class type so a child class could still use it for sorting in speciliazed collections?

Example

```
public class A
{
   public int X;
}

public class B:A
{
   public int Y;
}

public AComparer:IComparer<A>
{
    int Compare(A p1, A p2)
    {
        //...
    }

}
```

so following code will work:

```
List<A> aList = new List<A>();
aList.Sort(new AComparer());

List<B> bList = new List<B>();
bList.Sort(new AComparer()); // <- this line fails due to type cast issues
```

How to approach this issue to have both - inheritance of sorting and  specialized collections (and do not copy IComparer classes for each of children classes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, note that this is fixed in .NET 4 via *generic contravariance* - your code would simply work. EDIT: As noted in comments, generic variance was first supported in CLR v2, but various interfaces and delegates only became covariant or contravariant in .NET 4.

However, in .NET 2 it's still fairly easy to create a converter:

```
public class ComparerConverter<TBase, TChild> : IComparer<TChild>
    where TChild : TBase
{
    private readonly IComparer<TBase> comparer;

    public ComparerConverter(IComparer<TBase> comparer)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer;
    }

    public int Compare(TChild x, TChild y)
    {
        return comparer.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

You can then use:

```
List<B> bList = new List<B>();
IComparer<B> bComparer = new ComparerConverter<A, B>(new AComparer());
bList.Sort(bComparer);
```

EDIT: There's nothing you can do without changing the way of calling it *at all*. You could potentially make your `AComparer` generic though:

```
public class AComparer<T> : IComparer<T> where T : A
{
    int Compare(T p1, T p2)
    {
        // You can still access members of A here
    }    
}
```

Then you could use:

```
bList.Sort(new AComparer<B>());
```

Of course, this means making all your comparer implementations generic, and it's somewhat ugly IMO.

Comment: Works great but the problem is it delegates execution to the base class comparer but still changes the way of calling. If there is no better approach i will follow this one. Unfortunatelly I cannot use .NET 4.0

Comment: @Random: I've added another option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both ways are extremely useful and both are ugly :) I will stick to the first option and make my classes be reposponsible for exposing Comparers (practice found at MSDN). Thats how i will get common implementation way for the rest of developers at least.

Comment: @JonSkeet is generic contravariance a feature of .NET 4? I guess it would be C#..

Comment: @nawfal: Generic covariance was a feature of the CLR v2, C# v4, and introduced in framework libraries in .NET 4. I haven't tried it, but I think it *should* be possible to introduce your own variant interfaces/delegates when using (say) VS2010 and targeting .NET 2... but `IEnumerable<T>` won't be covariant in that situation.

Comment: @JonSkeet perfectly understand you, thanks! And your answer is amazing :)